# Forward monocular stereo vision (Structure from Motion)

Tags: stereo-vision, 3d-reconstruction, monocular, point-cloud, structure-from-motion

I am looking for a library (or algorithm) that computes 3D scene (point cloud) from 2 consecutive images of a monocular sequence. I mean something like [OpenSfM](https://github.com/mapillary/OpenSfM) but only for 2 consecutive frames and also with a known camera calibration data (I dont need to do "bundle adjustment" like most of the SfM libraries do). I do know my absolute camera translation for the scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this can easily be done with OpenCV - just find image features (FAST etc.) in first image, track them to the second image (get a set of corresponding features between two images) and then use triangulatePoints function to get the 3D scene.

triangulatePoints accepts two projection matrices - one for each image. Each projection matrix defines camera intrinsic (focal + principal point) and extrinsic (rotation + translation) parameters. Intrinsics will be the same for both images, first image may have R+t all zero (coordinates origin) so just use R+t for your second image (compared back to zero).

Comment: Glad you found an answer to your question! You can accept your own answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. This helps "close out" the question on the site and helps future visitors find the quality answers :)